# How to: Join 2 DataTables with same Row Count

Tags: c#, datatable

I've got these two DataTables:

Table1:
Columns->"Timestamp1,Result1"
Row[0]->"someTime,someResult"

Table2:
Columns->"Timestamp2,Result2"
Row[0]->"someotherTime", "someotherResult"

Now I want to get a result table or string[] or string like this:

Table Result:
Columns->"Timestamp1,Result1,Timestamp2,Result2"
Row[0]->"someTime,someResult,someotherTime,someotherResult"

Is there a simple Way of doing this? Even if the tables got more rows then one?

I've allready got some solution for joining the Columns to a string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataTable dt in data_set.Tables)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Join(",", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray()));
            sb.Append(",");                              
        }
```

Output with the example tables will be a String like this >> "Timestamp1, Result1,Timestamp2,Result2"

So using linq could be possible, but unfortunately I dont get it...

Could someone help me please?

Best regards

Edit:

Both tables should have the same count of rows! Merge will not work, because it will just not join one rows from two different tables into a new single one. Merge will just output 2 Rows in the new table.

Comment: you can just use Merge `dtAll = dtOne.Copy();
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);`

Comment: Doing a merge of the table puts all rows at the bottom of the existing table... What I THINK you are asking is a 1:1 ratio of rows  1st row from each table ON THE SAME OUTPUT LINE, then same for 2nd row, etc.  Please edit your question, confirm the intention.

Comment: @DRapp you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it on my own... this code looks for every column in dt2 and if it's not existing in dt1, it will start the copy process.

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in data_table2.Columns)
        {
            //Only new Columns
            if (!data_table1.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
            {
                //Add all new Columns to dt1
                data_table1.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);                    

                //interate over all rows
                foreach (DataRow dr in data_table2.Rows)
                {
                    //Copy single value from  dt2 in dt1
                    data_table1.Rows[dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr)][data_table1.Columns.IndexOf(dc.ColumnName)] = dr[dc.ColumnName];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

from your both tables, get the below result table  :

```
var resultTable = from t1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable() 
                     on t1.Field<int>("ID") equals t2.Field<int>("ID")
                 select new { t1, t2 };
```

then after apply your logic on resultTable for getting your result